# You've reached your limit of 0 GPUs NVIDIA K80 when start an instance with gpu on gcp

Tags: google-compute-engine

When I start a instance with gpu on google cloud platform, it shows me the error that `You've reached your limit of 0 GPUs NVIDIA K80.`

Anyone who can give me some tips about this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Contact Google support. GPUs cost extra.

Comment: yes, I try to pay the bill, but I can not find where to pay, and I also try to contract google support, but I they only provide support phone, and I cannot call international number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message “You've reached your limit of 0 GPUs NVIDIA K80” you received is because you tried to create an instance with GPUs, but you don’t have any quota for them.

You can request a [quota increase](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#gpus) following below steps:

1. Go to your Google Cloud Console and select your project.
2. Go to the Quotas page and choose the quota you want to increase.

   - (Optional) You can filter the Metric (in you case, NVIDIA K80 GPUs)
   - (Optional) You can also filter the Region accordingly, make sure the GPUs you choose is in the [available zones](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/)).

   As of June 2020 the available zones for NVIDIA K80 GPUs are:

   - asia-east1-a
   - asia-east1-b
   - europe-west1-b
   - europe-west1-d
   - us-central1-a
   - us-central1-c
   - us-east1-c
   - us-east1-d
   - us-west1-b
3. Click Edit Quotas, fill-in the form (your phone number, your request and justification), and click “Submit Request”.
4. You will receive a response from the Compute Engine team within 24 to 48 hours of your request (often much faster).

Here you have more detailed informations about [GPUs on Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/).

Comment: You often get your request approved much faster than that (within minutes).