# I can't use a graphics card on my vm

Tags: virtual-machines, google-compute-engine, gpu

I can't use a gpu on my vm and it says: Quota 'GPUS_ALL_REGIONS' exceeded. Limit: 0.0 globally all the time and I have premium so how do I fix this?

Comment: Are you on [free trial](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#end)?. If yes, you can't add GPUs to your VM instances. This is explained in the 'program coverage' section. You might need to [upgrade](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#how-to-upgrade) your account and then request for necessary quota change which is explained in the above [discussion](https://serverfault.com/questions/887256/youve-reached-your-limit-of-0-gpus-nvidia-k80-when-start-an-instance-with-gpu-o) thread.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the total available number of virtual GPUs in all VM instances in a region is lower than your current needs. 
To overcome this issue you can request a change of quota[1] and ask for fulfilling your current region.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#request_quotas